# Pressing F2 in Excel no longer enters edit mode

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I press F2 in Excel, the cell is not deleted instead of entering edit mode. Does anyone know what setting I need to change?

Comment: @user5389726598465 - This answer does not have any deleted answers.  Comments should not be used to answer a question.  However, commentary submitted as an answer, will be deleted by the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, press "F Lock" on your keyboard, it worked for me.